# Help with TransactionScope in EF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, transactionscope

I am new to TransactionScope. I Just want to make sure what i am doing is correct in the code below.

```
private void DoSomeWork()
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        context.Connection.Open();

        int ID = context.CallUpdateStoredProc();

        RecursiveDelete((EntityConnection)context.Connection, ID);

        context.Connection.Close();

        scope.Complete(); 
    }
}

private void RecursiveDelete(EntityConnection connection,int someID)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities(connection))
    {
        var UpdatedLinks = context.CallSaveStoredProc(someID).ToList();

        foreach (int UpdatedLink in UpdatedLinks)
        {
            RecursiveDelete(connection,UpdatedLink);     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of how you are using the [`TransactionScope` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx), yes, it is correct, you generally use the pattern of:

```
// Use overloads of constructor if you need to fine-tune the transaction
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{ 
    // Do your work.

    // Call Complete if the work is truly complete.
    // Note, if you determine through logic, you don't
    // have to call Complete.
    tx.Complete();
}
```

Once you call the [`Complete` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx), it will indicate that the curent [`Transaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.aspx) is ready to be committed.  Note that the transaction isn't committed at the time of the call to `Complete`, but when the `TransactionScope` is disposed.

From the documentation for `TransactionScope.Complete`:

> The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the
>   End Using statement if the TransactionScope object created the
>   transaction.

Also, as indicated in the comments in the sample code, it's a conscious decision whether or not the call to `Complete` should be made.

Again, from the documentation for `TransactionScope.Complete` (emphasis mine):

> **When you are satisfied** that all operations within the scope are
>   completed successfully, you should call this method only once to
>   inform that transaction manager that the state across all resources is
>   consistent, and the transaction can be committed.

Now, as for whether or not `TransactionScope` can be used with the Entity Framework, the answer is yes, as the documentation on MSDN titled ["How to: Manage Transactions in the Entity Framework"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx) indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework 4 is TransactionScope aware, so your example will work fine. See [this example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx).